# transpose 250,000 rows into columns in R

Tags: r

I always transpose by using t(file) command in R.
But i it is not running properly (not running at all) on big data file (250,000 rows and 200 columns).  Any ideas.

I need to calculate correlation between 2nd row (PTBP1) with all other rows (except 8 rows including header). In order to do this I transpose rows to columns and then use cor function.

But I struck at transpose fn. Any help would be really appreciated!

I copied example from one of the post in stackoverflow (They are also almost discussing the same problem but seems no answer yet!)

```
ID A B C D E F G H I [200 columns]
Row0$-1 0.08 0.47 0.94 0.33 0.08 0.93 0.72 0.51 0.55
Row02$1 0.37 0.87 0.72 0.96 0.20 0.55 0.35 0.73 0.44
Row03$ 0.19 0.71 0.52 0.73 0.03 0.18 0.13 0.13 0.30
Row04$- 0.08 0.77 0.89 0.12 0.39 0.18 0.74 0.61 0.57
Row05$- 0.09 0.60 0.73 0.65 0.43 0.21 0.27 0.52 0.60
Row06-$ 0.60 0.54 0.70 0.56 0.49 0.94 0.23 0.80 0.63
Row07$- 0.02 0.33 0.05 0.90 0.48 0.47 0.51 0.36 0.26
Row08$_ 0.34 0.96 0.37 0.06 0.20 0.14 0.84 0.28 0.47
........
250,000 rows
```

Comment: You want a quarter of a million *columns*?  Or is that a typo in your question's title?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not running properly'?  Not running at all, takes a long time, or gives wrong results?

Comment: @Jeff - depends whether the number in the title or the question body is the correct one.

Comment: You probably have done a read operation where you got tripped up by a non-numeric value that resulted in creation of a factor column. Instead of "showing" us the print()-ed version you should show us the str()-ed version.

Answer (score 2):

Use a matrix instead. The only advantage of a dataframe over a matrix is the capacity to have different classes in the columns and you clearly do not have that situation, since a transposed dataframe could not support such a result.

Comment: Yes, although that's far from a free operation either. Real question here is "why?"...

Comment: Agree that "why" is a good question. My point was that there were constraints on the situations where it would make sense.

Comment: Data frame is a list of columns, and list allocates some extra data for each element -- matrix is just a 1D vector.

Comment: I do not see why "why" is a good question, this forum is about answering questions not question OP intent

Comment: My understanding of the "why" question was "please explain why a matrix would better support the requested operation but a dataframe would not." The answer is that operations on dataframe need to allow for the possibility of varying classes in their columns and are therefore often slower than matrix operations. I also think it is perfectly appropriate to question posters' intent. Sometimes they should be advised that their approach is either inefficient, or that they are making statistical assumptions that are incorrect, or they are simply posting in the wrong forum.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you want to transpose the data.frame. If you just use `cor` it doesn't matter if your data is in rows or columns.
Actually, it is one of the major advantages of R that it doen's matter if your data fits in the classical row-column pattern as SPSS and others programs require data to be.

There are numerous ways to correlate the first row with all other rows (I don't get which rows you want to exclude). One is using a loop (here the loop is implicit in the call to one of the *apply family functions):

```
lapply(2:(dim(fn)[1]), function(x) cor(fn[1,],fn[x,]))
```

Note that I expect you data.frame to ba called fn. To skip some rows change the 2 to the number you want. Furthermore, I would probably use `vapply` here.

I hope this answer points you in the correct direction and that is to not use `t()` if you absolutely don't need it.

Comment: i'm getting this error"Error in cor(fn[1, ], fn[x, ]) : 'x' must be numeric". If i transpose and calculate the correlation using cor i get some thing like this . TSPAN6$chrX$99770450$99771639$-$0.372356495468 vs PTBP1 = 0.25...

Comment: check `fn[1,]`. This must be a numeric vector (try `class(fn[1,])`). Otherwise, change 1 to the appropriate row that is numeric and the basis fopr your correlation analysis. If your first row is really called `Name` and is not the header, everything in `df` is a factor or a charcter and this is the problem. (the error message you get indicate that `fn[1,]` is not numeric)

Comment: fn[,1] showed PTBP1 and all other headers like NA19099_argonne NA18510_argonne NA18520_arg .......And I tried class function and it showed it as a data frame. Thanx for the help Henrik!

Comment: Every element in your data.frame is a factor (or character). To get what you want, try to create a new data.frame and then run my code on the new data.frame. To create a new df that does not contain factors do: `fn.new <- as.numeric(as.character(fn[-1,]))` Then run my code (exchange every instance of `fn` to `fn.new`).

Comment: you could also try: `lapply(3:(dim(fn)[1]), function(x) cor(as.numeric(as.character(fn[2,])), as.numeric(as.character(fn[x,]))))` on your original fn dataset.